# Chrome Native Messaging does not work on Windows if the user is not an administrator

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I developed a Chrome extension that uses [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging) communication.

I am working in a Windows environment. Everything works fine if I am logged in as an administrator user. But when I log in as a non-administrator user, the extension does not connect to the host application anymore. It simply does not work.

No error messages are shown at the extension's background page log.

If I [enable chrome logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging), by launching Chrome from the terminal using the `--enable-logging --v=1` flag, no messages are shown when the extension tries to connect to the host application.

My manifest file:

```
{
  "description": "App",
  "path": "app.bat",
  "name": "com.example.app",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://<extension_id_here>/"
  ]
}
```

My `app.bat` file:

```
@echo off

call java -jar app.jar
```

Is anyone able to make Native Messaging work when logged in as a non-administrator user?

Comment: Could be because you've installed the host app or java machine under the administrator user only.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @Veer3383 Sorry for the late response. The problem in fact was related with the Windows registries. I was adding the path to the manifest file to HKEY_CURRENT_USER. It worked when I changed to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.